S4 class with base function works fine but generates warning (?) when loading
I have an S4 class myClass in myPackage and it works as expected. I added some generic functions like length() and show() and these work without a problem.
I now want to add support for the generic function format() to pretty-print my class data. The signature of format() is:
> format
standardGeneric for "format" defined from package "base"

function (x, ...) 
standardGeneric("format")
<environment: 0x13f91ffb0>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods(format)  for currently available ones.

For my function I am using the following definition:
> setMethod("format", "myClass", function(x, fmt) {
  ...
})

The function works as expected but when I load my package I get the warning (?):
> devtools::load_all(".")
ℹ Loading myPackage
in method for ‘format’ with signature ‘"myClass"’: no definition for class “myClass”

What is it that I am missing here? Is this something to do with the signature of my function compared to the generic ...? I've read up on Hadley and other sources but no luck on this one - any help much appreciated.

Do you have an example repository? If I make a new package containing the following two lines setClass("myClass", slots = c(name = "character")); setMethod("format", "myClass", function(x, fmt) x) then I can load without problem. I saw the same message as you when I only had setMethod() (i.e when the class was not defined)

Problem solved. The solution is to have the definition of the function in the same R script as the definition of the class.
I have not seen this documented anywhere. I'll make a note in Hadley's Advanced R GitHub repo.

It is documented in the (currently) first paragraph of the "Package subdirectories" section in the "Writing R Extensions" manual: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/doc/manual/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories

@MikaelJagan I take it you refer to: "If computations are required to create objects these can use code ‘earlier’ in the package". In my opinion that is a very obscure way (location, description) of describing this requirement. But thanks for pointing it out anyway.

Yes, I was referring to that line, which I intended to quote, but didn't (sorry).  I agree that the documentation here could be improved.  Another reason is that setClass is a canonical example of a function with side effects, yet it says "R code files ... definitely should not call functions with side effects".

@MikaelJagan Thanks for the elaboration. I'll flag this post in the Adv R repo
